# What are the differences between desktop environments in Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, kubuntu, desktop-environments, distro-recommendation

For example, in some distributions like Debian, the same CD netinst allows you to choose one or all of the desktop environments (Gnome, Xfce, etc...) but in Ubuntu you actually have to choose between different distros or forks (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu...)

What's the difference between having a distro like xubuntu and installing ubuntu and then doing something like

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

What's the difference between ubuntu with xfce and Xubuntu? Why are they called "flavours" instead of just different desktop environments?

Comment: Distribution is more than just desktop environment. Each distribution comes with a specific set of tools.

Comment: The different flavours are pre-configured setups - different apps, different themes, different wallpapers etc.. You could install xfce & the other relevant items and spend time to get essentially the same result as Xubuntu - the Xubuntu distro & package does it all for you though